# Скопировать данные с pdf файла

Tags: pdf

Получен файл pdf, при копировании слова из файла выдает символы, которые не читаются.

ПРИМЕР : **Laboratory : „—w•˜—‡•˜ˆ**

Вопрос : Как скопировать данные из полученного файла pdf ?, чтобы не переписывать вручную необходимые данные сверяя каждую букву (заказчик не может отправить иной формат или другой файл, поэтому необходимо работать с полученным файлом)

p.s. файл не прикладываю по понятным причинам, но варианты ответов получить стоит от тех кто сталкивался и решил как то

вот скрин с clipboardview
[image: вот скрин с clipboardview]

а вот заметка в файле, по которой я вела поиски, но не нашла пока ничего дельного, возможно это как сказал в ответе S.H. что какие либо скрипты выплняются в процессе работы с документом[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Присобачте хотя бы фрагмент файла к вопросу, чтобы можно было его изучить.

Comment: Довольно извесный глюк, думаю почти каждый сталкивался с невозможность скопировать из некоторых pdf, с одних копируется нормально, а с других почему-то нет. Но и правда, приложите файл, для образца. Если не получтается приложить - нагуглите какой-нибудь уже выложеный для примера и кинте ссылку.

Comment: А как вы хотите решить эту проблему? Что вы сделали? Вы скачали прогу clipboard-анализатор? Как вы представляете решить проблему? Вы хотите сделать плагин, написать программу на с++ или на с# или на делфи, и что она будет делать? Вы хотите пересобрать pdf? Вот обсуждение более внятное https://forum.ixbt.com/topic.cgi?id=23:40806

Comment: файл к сожалению приложить не могу,так как клиентские данные, но @nick_n_a предложил очень интересное обсуждение, пробовала варианты предложенные там, там был коммментарий и говорилось про notePad и  конверт черезTigerPad, так как мне незнакома программа TigerPad я ее не скачала(просто в notePad испробовала с заменой кодировки, не сработало)...потом через онлайн конверт маленькую часть фразы вставила...не сработало, с файлом что именно собиралась делать это нужно обновить данные в программе и там инфа, но это я уже сделала вручную. т.к. это не в первой с pdf файлом вопрос чисто для сообщества

Comment: А нормальный текст какой для примера? Или вы сами не можете определить?

Comment: Я попробовал тут https://felicita.kharkov.ua/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/pdf-blank.pdf и ещё пару в сети найти - не удалось глюк поймать.

Comment: @nick_n_a, А вы старайтесь больше, может, эксплоит найдете ))) Вместо `Laboratory : „—w•˜—‡•˜ˆ` что должно быть?

Comment: Предоставьте или файл, или скрин с того же clipboardview

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Вместо „—w•˜—‡•˜ˆ должно быть Laboratory

Comment: Это Windows 10? Какая дефаултная кодовая страница? Какой язык раскладки стоит при копировании и вставке? Копируемый текст на русском или английском? Текст в pdf - это картинка с текстовым слоем или реально текст?

Comment: @Qwertiy Windows 10 Professionnel, дефаултная- AsobeAcrobatReader?если я правильно поняла вопрос, раскладка стоит французская, но и и при английской такой же каракуль копируется и копиПастом тоже, копируемый текст на французском.

Comment: Не то. Кодовая страница для неюникодных программ. Например, для кириллицы 1251.

Comment: а где смотреть на кодовую страницу ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9nel.png - похоже, число из интерфейса спрятали - теперь просто "Русский (Россия)". Открывается так: Настройки языка -> Регион -> Дополнительные параметры даты, времени, региона -> Изменение форматов даты, времени, чисел -> Дополнительно.

Comment: [Français (France)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте программы вроде

- http://freeclipboardviewer.com/windowsclipboard
- https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/inside_clipboard.html
  Или любую
  другую найти по тегу "clipboard view". Видел и фирмы микрософт похожую вещь то ли в пакете с студией - быстро не нашёл. Если попадается платная - пропускайте смело берите другую. Пишется похожая неочень долго.

Особенность буфера обмена в том, что буфер обмена может хранить в себе информацию в разных видах "одновременно" (если не одновременно, то по крайней мере умеет перекодировать в один из нескольких извесных форматов). Вполне может такое быть, что cf_text будет сожержать "битую" информацию, а unicode text, или html text (если копируется с мозилла-фаэрфокс, например) содержать информацию в нормальном виде. Информацию эту уже можно обработать и пересохранить в нормальном виде. Имея ввиду что не всегда программа-получатель может выбирать правильный формат из доступных, это может решить даную проблему.

Так же, буфер обмена доступен из под WinAPI, и при владении с++/c#/Delphi/python или другими, написание программы которая достает из clipboard данные - не очень сложная задача.

P.S. Давно не пользовался акробатом и фокситом, возможно в фоксе это вылечили, попробуйте firefox.

Answer (score 5):

А что, если вообще не копировать, а увеличить шрифт в пдф до 200%, например, и прогнать через экранную распознавалку, типа ScreenshotReader?

Дело в том, что PDF - это чудовищно сложный формат. Вы же знаете, что в PDF документ можно встроить, к примеру, простую игру? то есть, что формат предполагает, чтов документы встроено подмножество JavaScript, и эти скрипты выплняются в процессе работы с документом. [Пруф](https://habr.com/ru/company/vdsina/blog/536200/)

В то же время, распознавание компьютерного шрифта с экрана, когда нет никакого "шума", как при сканировании-распознавании, практически не даёт ошибок.

А дальше - всё зависит от объема. При маленьком объеме - можно воспользоваться "триальным" (15 дней) [скриншот ридером](https://www.abbyy.com/ru/download/screenshot-reader/trial/), при более значительных объемах можно как то "накостылять" (у программистов этот термин отличается от общепринятого) из программы автоматизации действий пользователя и распознавалки, в т.ч. поискать что то freeware для распознавания.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря куда копируете. Скорее всего у вас кодировки в файлах разные UTF например и ANSI. Откройте не через ПДФ вивер(или что там у вас стоит). А через НотПад++, например. Изображения перенести просто. Текст можно попробовать так.